Which of the following peppers falls under the classification of what Australians call capiscums?
I have learned that Australia calls bell peppers "capiscums", and that chili peppers and jalapeno peppers also fall under "capiscums" too, though Australians will just say chili and jalapenos for those. If you say green peppers, red peppers, or yellow peppers, then, you would hear green capiscum, red capiscum, and yellow capiscum instead.
Salt and pepper still stays as "salt and pepper", though Australians also have a special salt called "chicken salt", which is used for hot chips sometimes.
Now, the question is how about these pepper types: banana peppers, lemon peppers, peppercorn sauce, and vine peppers? I think banana peppers may fall under capiscum, but what about the other 3?

I'm not Australian, but the pepper 'fruits' are capSIcums, as distinct from peppercorns which are a spice.

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question about English - it is a botany question about whether certain varieties fall under a genus of plant.

They're not called capsicums in the supermarkets in the US; that's not an "everyday" term here.

Do some research! Find out what the different ingredients are, many of which are botanically unrelated - salt and peppercorns are not capsicums, are used differently, and look unlike. Australians call peppercorns pepper (as you say). What does this have to do with chicken salt (salt with chicken powder), lemon pepper (peppercorns and lemon peel), or peppercorn sauce (a sauce made from peppercorns)?? It's reasonable to ask what name is given to banana peppers and vine peppers in Australia (I believe the latter are sold as baby capsicums) but these have nothing to do with peppercorns.

@MichaelHarvey - That's what I meant to imply - but it's CAP-SI-CUM, not CAP-IS-CUM.

@KateBunting - I have no excuse!

Your question about whether certain varieties are classed as capsicums is more of a botany question than an English one. A quick Google should get you the answer to that.
But I thought maybe it would be helpful if I reframe the question slightly and ask instead: is it unusual for a generic term like 'capsicum' to be used for a specific variety of something?
Some nouns are different across dialects of English. For example, both the British and Americans use the term 'marrow' (sometimes marrow squash in the USA) to describe the same vegetable, but when it comes to the smaller, immature marrows they use different words - the British use the French word courgette while Americans use the Italian word zucchini, both of which basically mean 'baby marrow' by using the diminutive suffixes from each language.
As you have learned, 'capsicum' is a broad term that describes all peppers including chilli peppers. What Americans call 'bell peppers', the British just call 'peppers', as if they are the standard pepper and all other varieties need to be named, although sometimes they are also called 'sweet peppers'. Australians using the family name "capsicums" for one specific variety is not unusual. It is often the case that the first type of something introduced into a dialect gets the broadest name and everything else is a subvariety of it. Tomatoes, for example, have many varieties, but most people will have a standard variety in mind that they just call 'tomatoes' and everything else has a specific name like cherry tomatoes and plum tomatoes. So, the most common variety of something doesn't need a prefix or a specific name to be identified.
This also happens with other items, not just food varieties. For example, Americans tend to refer to any kind of soft tissue paper as a 'Kleenex', even though that is just one brand. Likewise, some British people call the vacuum cleaner a 'Hoover' and even use 'hoovering' as a verb.
So to sum up - it isn't so unusual that Australians call the 'standard' variety of pepper by the name that other English dialects use as a broader term for the whole genus of peppers. It seems pretty clear that when they say 'capsicum' as a specific term it means the same as what Americans call 'bell peppers', so all the less-common varieties you are asking about probably would not fall under that term. The very fact that a 'banana pepper' has a specific name in the dialect you are familiar with shows that it isn't what Americans would classify as a bell pepper.

"[This] is more of a botany question than an English one. A quick Google should get you the answer to that" —It seems to me it's not as simple as that. My first google hit for "Australian term for peppers" gives me this chunk of the Wikipedia article 'Capsicum'. It looks to me like the Aussies (and Indians and New Zealanders) use it for only certain members of that family. I took the OP's question as being "Ok, where do they draw the line?"

@AndyBonner Moot point as the question is now closed.

Well, I don't have the energy to mount a campaign for it, but I feel like the closure was misguided as well. It doesn't seem to me to be about botany but about regional usages and to be well within our focus.
